# state passed through history.push not accessible in redirected class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router

I have a case where I have to redirect from one page to another page and pass the state as prop to redirected page. I have used history.push and trying to access it as
`console.log(this.props.location.state.searchString)` but I get and error on location that, `Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`.

I am using react router and typescript.

My history.push code snippet

```
    class HomePageContent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, HomePageState> {
    
        constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value: ''
            }
        }
 

   

<Input ....
    onKeyDown={evt => {
            if(evt.detail.key=='Enter')
            {
            this.props.history.push
             ({
                pathname: '/resultspage',
                state: { searchString : this.state.value }
             });
           }
    />
...}
export default withRouter(HomePageContent);
```

And my redirected component code,

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.location.state.searchString);
        return (......);}
```

Do I have to declare `props` somewhere here in the redirected class?

My App.tsx looks like this,

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import {name} from '../package.json';
    import HomePage from './Components/HomePage/index';
    import SearchResults from "./Components/SearchResults/index";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router basename={ `/${name}` }>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/resultspage" component={SearchResults} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone tell me how to access this prop on redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path to

```
path="/resultspage/:searchString"
```

Then change your push function argument to

```
this.props.history.push(`/resultspage/${searchString}`)
```

Then in your SearchResults components

```
 const { searchResult } = useParams();
```

Comment: I tried this using this.props.match.params.searchResult but it says that searchResult does not exist on type {}

I wrapped the class in withRouter

Comment: post a code sandbox example and try to reproduce the error otherwise I do not have enough information to debug it

Comment: I am able to console log it in `render()` but not assign it in constructor to a state. Is this not allowed?  I get an error Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
My constructor looks like this, 
`constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>){
        
super(props);
        
this.state = {
            SearchString: this.props.match.params
        
}
    
}`

Comment: Use this.props.match.params.searchTerm

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-northcutt-egvgx?file=/src/SearchResults.tsx

I can set the state only if I keep the datatype to any and it does not work for string datatype